# Collecting P-values using a Loop in R

Tags: r

Ran a bunch of regressions and now I am trying to collect their p values and put them into a vector.

```
x=summary(reg2)$coefficients[4,4]   #p value from the first regression, p-val is in row 4, col 4

for (i in 3:1000){

  currentreg=summary(paste("reg",i,sep=""))
  assign(x,c(x,currentreg$coefficients[4,4]))

}
```

I also tried `eval(parse(currentreg))` and `eval(parse(summary(paste("reg",i,sep=""))))` with no luck. I always have this problem with telling R "Hey don't treat this as a string, treat it as a variable" and vice versa.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you just stored the models in a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it would be better to store the objects in a list and loop over that, you're asking for `get`:

```
currentreg <- summary(get(paste("reg", i, sep="")))
```

If you had a list of objects, `models <- list(reg2, reg3, reg4, ...)`.  You can then loop over this list with `sapply` to achieve the desired result (looping, collecting the results into a vector):

```
x <- sapply(models, function(z) { summary(z)$coeficients[4,4] })
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^reg\\d+$")), function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[4,4])
```

to create a vector with all p-values.